# Accessing config variable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, config

Under my config folder I have a constants.php file.  I have accessed pressMetadata object in the constant file using `{{ json_encode(config('constants.pressMetadata')) }}`.  This dumps all the data as a JSON object.  What I am trying to do is print out all the data using a foreach loop.  I have tried

```
@foreach (config('constants.pressMetadata') as $tile)
          <p>{{$tile->id}}</p>
@endforeach
```

This does not work.  So what should I do so I can use a foreach loop to iterate through the object at config('constants.pressMetadata')?

Here is constants pressMetadata

```
'pressMetadata'=>[
      "AARP" => [
          "id" => 1,
          "company" => "AARP",
          "title" => "Updating Your Résumé for the Digital Age",
          "url" => "http://www.aarp.org/work/job-hunting/info-2016/give-resume-a-digital-reboot.html",
          "date" => "Sep 9, 2016"
      ],
      "Business Insider" => [
          "id" => 2,
          "company" => "Business Insider",
          "title" => "8 things you should always include on your résumé",
          "url" => "http://www.businessinsider.com/what-to-always-include-on-your-resume-2016-1",
          "date" => "Jan 28, 2016"
      ],
      "Morning Journal" => [
          "id" => 3,
          "company" => "Morning Journal",
          "title" => "5 things you missed: Google updates search, Jobscan and more",
          "url" => "http://www.morningjournal.com/article/MJ/20140124/NEWS/140129366",
          "date" => "Jan 24, 2014"
      ],
],
```

Comment: Show the `config/constants.php` config please.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, I added constants.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's array of arrays, do this:

```
@foreach (config('constants.pressMetadata') as $tile)
    <p>{{ $tile['id'] }}</p>
@endforeach
```